# mutable boost::mutex is it possible to separate lock and wait functions?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, mutex, mutable

So I have functions like `read` that can be called at the same time from multiple threads. but  also I have a function to `write` that needs to lock all that `read` functions. Where to get example of creating such archetecture?

I get that we can have:

```
mutable boost::mutex the_read_mutex;
mutable boost::mutex the_write_mutex;
```

and:

```
void write()
{
    // make all new readers wait and wait for all other currently running read threads();
}

void read()
{
    // do not make all new readers wait, and wait for all currently running write thread()
}
```

So how to do such thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
boost::shared_mutex  m

Reader()
 shared_lock   lock(m)

Writer()
 upgradeable_lock lck(m)
 upgrade_to_unique_lock uniqueLock(lck);
```

To know more about boost-locks : [Boost thread sync mechanisms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html)

To know about the class of the problem you are dealing with : [Wikpedia Link to Reader-WriterLock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writer_lock)

To know more about POSIX reader-writer lock, which directly gives you reader write lock with much simple syntax : [POSIX reader-witer locks](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/apis/rzah4mst.htm)

Comment: @kabumbus : That is why SHARED lock. :)  More than 1 reader can take the same shared_lock without being blocked.

Comment: @Kabumbus The whole idea behind a reader-writer lock implementation is to allow readers concurrent access, but if any writer needs access it must wait until all other readers or any writer has relinquished ownership of the resource. Also, neither readers nor writers will be granted access while a writer has ownership.

Comment: ... I do not see upgradeable_lock  in boost...=(

Comment: @Kabumbus : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.locks.upgrade_lock